# Declarative authorization and the if_attribute not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, conditional-statements, authlogic, declarative-authorization

I've been having almost the same issues as [Victor Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547352/if-attribute-syntax-problem-on-declarative-authorization) (you can see the questions asked here).

I've got declarative authorization working for just about everything that doesn't involve using conditionals. E.g.

```
has_permission_on :users, :to => [:edit, :update, :destroy] do
if_attribute :user => is { current_user }
end
```

Are there any common pitfalls with Declarative Authorization? I'm using authlogic and I'm suspicious the 'current_user' method in the application controller might be the source of the problem.

Comment: I ended up using cancan for authorizaiton - I highly recommend it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that if you are using "filter_access_to" in your controllers, you need to make sure you have ":attribute_check => true". Without it, the conditional "if_attribute" declarations don't do anything.

More details about this [in the Declarative Authorization docs](http://www.tzi.org/~sbartsch/declarative_authorization/master/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this to your ApplicationController if you haven't already:

```
before_filter :set_current_user
protected
def set_current_user
  Authorization.current_user = current_user
end
```

Then your rules would look like this:

```
has_permission_on :users, :to => [:edit, :update, :destroy] do
  if_attribute :user => is { user }
end
```

As far as I know declarative_authorization doesn't call any methods on the crontroller and doesn't know what `current_user` means in your example, but it give's you an instance of `Authorization.current_user` called `user` that you can use in your `authorization_rules.rb` file.

Comment: OK, I tried using 'user' instead of 'current_user'. Now I've done that I pretty much have all of the above but it still doesn't work. :/

Comment: Do you get errors or just "permission denied"? What is your log saying?